# How to run socket.io on subdomain?

Tags: node.js, apache, ubuntu, socket.io

I am not sure it is actually subdomain or not but **'/etc/apache2/sites-available/ooo-default.conf'** file contains following code -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =app.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

My project is kept under **'/var/www/html/beta'** directory , there is no **'app'** directory presented at **'/var/www/html'**

How can I run socket io here? My server is - Linux Ubuntu 16.04

I find following solution -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app.mydomain.com

    <Location "/">
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

But it is not working, when I add this codes in **'/etc/apache2/sites-available/ooo-default.conf'** file , apache2 stops working. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure you have `mod_proxy` enabled? Also I believe it should be `ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/` (note the `/` before url), and similar for the reverse proxy.

Comment: No I didn't enable it, will it be secure ? As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606226/send-subdomain-to-node-js , I have to enable more apache mod.

Answer (score 3):

Using the following steps:

**1)** Update virtual file:-

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@test.com
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
  ProxyRequests Off Order deny,allow Allow from all
 <Location />
        ProxyPass http:// mysite.com:8000/
        ProxyPassReverse http:// mysite.com:8000/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

**2)** Enabling Necessary Apache Modules

To enable these four modules, execute the following commands in succession.

```
sudo a2enmod proxy

sudo a2enmod proxy_http

sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer

sudo a2enmod lbmethod_byrequests
```

**3)** To put these changes into effect, restart Apache.

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```